# Calendar instead of jQuery-UI DatePicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The jQuery-UI DatePicker is wonderful but it is a DatePicker. I need a Calendar widget that is not triggered off an input field or such and the calendar is just displayed all the time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is a fairly good one.

However, if you still want the basic functionality of the DatePicker, but just want it always shown you can display it inline instead.

Just call `.datepicker()` on a div instead of an input. [See here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/inline.html) for an example.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by display it "inline"?

Comment: @Sam Gentile, inline basically means that it is always shown as part of the page. You don't need to click an input in order for it to be visible. Take a look at the example and you'll see that the calendar is already visible, no clicking necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In fact jQuery UI's Datepicker can be used as a [simple inline Calendar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline).

It is also used here in SO. You can see it in your profile, in the `visited` row click on `x days, y consecutive` to see it.